# How I display phone's mp3 files list in one window in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to make music player in windows phone 8 using code behind language c# and design in XAML. I want to display mp3 file list of phone in one window.

How I display phone's mp3 files list in one window ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to make a list of your the songs that are present inside the phones media library then

make a base class SongModel

```
public class SongModel
{
    public int songId { get; set; }
    public string songName { get; set; }
}
```

Make global variables

```
MediaLibrary mLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
SongCollection songs;
List<SongModel> songnames;
```

now in the pages constructor write these lines of code

```
songs = mLibrary.Songs;
MediaPlayer.ActiveSongChanged += MediaPlayer_ActiveSongChanged;
MediaPlayer.MediaStateChanged += MediaPlayer_MediaStateChanged;
if (songs.Count != 0)
{
    songnames = new List<SongModel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < songs.Count; i++)
    {
        songnames.Add(new SongModel() { songName = songs[i].Name, songId = i });
    }
    lbMusic.ItemsSource = songnames; // lbMusic is the list/listbox here
}
```

xaml for listbox lbMusic

```
<ListBox  SelectionChanged="lbMusic_SelectionChanged" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" Name="lbMusic" Height="210" Width="480" Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate> 
            <StackPanel Margin="0,5,0,5" Width="480" Background="White" Height="40">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding songName}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="30,0,0,0" Tag="{Binding songId}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

To play a song based on its song ID, Ovveride the selectionChanged event of the listbox.

```
private void lbMusic_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (lbMusic.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            int musicId = (lbMusic.SelectedItem as SongModel).songId;
            MediaPlayer.Play(songs, musicId);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show(TextResources.resErrorActiveSong);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps as expected

Comment: Hello Amu, I want to know also one more thing if you will help me ? I want to change song of media player by it's song id how I will change it ? And songs list that I was passed to media player that remains same.